# Spring Boot + DB2 + Java8 = ClassNotFoundException: sun.io.ByteToCharConverter When Connection Pool Created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, db2, java-8

Getting a `ClassNotFoundException: sun.io.ByteToCharConverter` when Spring Boot first loads & attempts to create a connection pool.

Using:

- Java 8
- spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.7.RELEASE
- DB2's 10.5fp6 JDBC driver

Exception:

```
2015-12-03 07:46:44,588 DEBUG: [SqlExceptionHelper] - SQL Warning
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlWarning: Origination unknown: [10228][11541][4.16.53] Secu
rity exceptions occurred while loading driver. ERRORCODE=4223, SQLSTATE=null
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.b(fd.java:207)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.fd.b(fd.java:258)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hb.a(hb.java:1326)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.initConnection(Connection.java:710)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:687)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:334)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:233)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:199)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:474)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:708)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:642)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:464)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:141)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1048)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:825)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
        at com.comerica.tir.monitor.app.MonitorApplication.main(MonitorApplication.java:24)Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.io.ByteToCharConverter
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hb.x(hb.java:1312)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hb.<clinit>(hb.java:659)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:125)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.io.ByteToCharConverter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mg.run(mg.java:19)
        ... 44 more
```

...however, using the same JDBC driver in Squirrel SQL to connect to said database works perfectly fine.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It is solved in a completely different manner, as solved by the co-lead of spring boot:

https://twitter.com/phillip_webb/status/672423246562635776

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC74895

Specifying "-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3" on the Java command line solves the problem.

Comment: In my case `-Ddb2.jcc.charsetDecoderEncoder=3` didn't solve the issue